# Controlling or deugging validation behavior of SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

After investigating a production issue, I have found a number of references to SSIS packages getting stuck in 'validation' when run with DTEXEC or through as SQL Agent job steps.

Specifics of my situation aside, is there a technique to make this more robust so that in a production environment, I am notified if a job starts, but does not complete?

Is it possible to have a timeout period on validation so that the execution explicitly fails? Or have a way to specify number of retries?

Comment: If these other references had solutions of some sort, think about them to see if any seem generally applicable. If they did not have solutions (or at least definitive confirmation of the problem), realize that their interpretation of the problem may not actually have been correct.